# MSVC error with operator |

Tags: c++, templates, visual-c++

I am working on a library that makes extensive use of C++ templates. While writing I came to situation with code like this (of course simplified):

```
#include <sstream>

namespace ns{
    template<class A, class B>
    class c{};

    class a{};

    template<class A>
    class b{
    public:
        template<class B>
        auto
        take(A, B){
            return c<A, B>{};
        }
    };

    template<class A>
    auto
    make_b(A){
        return b<A>{};
    }

    template<class A, class B>
    auto
    operator|(A _a, B _b){
        return _b.take(_a, _b);
    }

}

using namespace ns;

int main(){
    a{} | make_b(a{});
    return 0;
}
```

While compiling it with msvc 19 (Visual Studio 2017) I get following class of errors:

> /opt/compiler-explorer/windows/19.10.25017/lib/native/include/xlocale(314): warning C4530: C++ exception handler used, but unwind semantics are not enabled. Specify /EHsc
>   (28): error C2228: left of '.take' must have class/struct/union
>   (28): note: type is ''
>
> /opt/compiler-explorer/windows/19.10.25017/lib/native/include/xstring(2923): note: see reference to function template instantiation 'auto ns::operator |(A,B)' being compiled
>           with
>           [
>               A=unsigned int,
>               B=
>           ]
>   /opt/compiler-explorer/windows/19.10.25017/lib/native/include/xstring(2922): note: while compiling class template member function 'void std::basic_string,std::allocator>::shrink_to_fit(void)'
>
> /opt/compiler-explorer/windows/19.10.25017/lib/native/include/system_error(658): note: see reference to function template instantiation 'void std::basic_string,std::allocator>::shrink_to_fit(void)' being compiled
>
> /opt/compiler-explorer/windows/19.10.25017/lib/native/include/stdexcept(22): note: see reference to class template instantiation 'std::basic_string,std::allocator>' being compiled

Removing `using namespace` works, but I do not want to forbid it (why should I?). Is there a solution?

EDIT: Of course I tested code with GCC and Clang - compiles under GCC from 4.9 and clang3 so it is solely MSVC issue.

EDIT2: I took a look at the reported errors and it seems like MSVC is extending the scope of overloaded `operator|` inside its standard library when using `using namespace`.

Comment: A) If it doesn't compile, maybe you aren't asking about optimization?
B) Maybe you want to post the actual error messages?

Comment: Sorry, edited comment, `couse made a mistake.

Comment: Just looked at your code on `godbolt` and you have missed off the 1st error message, please include it in your post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works this way, but i can't explain why it doesn't work original way, hope it will help somebody else.

Though my guess is that your template is *too broad* and it gets intantiated by some code from std library. Actually your code also works if your just comment out any std headers or remove `using namespace ns`.

```
namespace ns {
    template<class A, class B>
    class c {};

    class a {};

    template<class A>
    class b {
    public:
        using MyA = A;
        template<class B>
        auto
            take(A, B) {
            return c<A, B>{};
        }
    };

    template<class A>
    auto
        make_b(A) {
        return b<A>{};
    }

    template<class B>
    auto
        operator|(typename B::MyA _a, B _b) {
        return _b.take(_a, _b);
    }
}
```

Comment: I must say this is very interesting. You just added this `using MyA = A`?

Comment: @bartop yes, that's it

Comment: I guess the template is not too broad as gcc and clang accept it. More like msvc does something dirty inside it's library assuming none will ever do something I did.